# NullPointerException on AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()) in a Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a few Fragment classes that open through a `drawer`. And on some classes the buttons don't work, and on the others they work. I have the same code on all of them. I get the `error` on the `AlertDialog.builder` line:

```
public class NumbersActivity extends Fragment {

    private Spinner editAlarmSpinner;
    private Button deleteSelected, updateSelected, add;
    String prevAlarmName;
    DBAdapter db;
    ArrayList<String> alarmsList, allList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    final Context contextUpdate = getActivity();

    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        NumbersActivity f = new NumbersActivity();

        return f;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_numbers, container, false);

        editAlarmSpinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.editAlarmSpinner);
        deleteSelected = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        updateSelected = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.updateNumberButton);
        add = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addNumberButton);

        db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        updateSpinner();

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();   

                View promptView =  layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.updatenumberdialog, null, false);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextUpdate);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.newAlarmDetails);
```

What am i doing wrong? And why this works on other classes and on others it doesn't?

Comment: have you tried after initializing `contextUpdate = getActivity();
` inside onCreateView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change from

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contextUpdate);
```

to

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

or initialize your

```
contextUpdate = getActivity();
```

inside onCreateView.

Comment: @AntonisLambrianides You'r wel come. Glad to help you!!

Answer (score 0):

`contextUpdate` is `null` because you're calling `Fragment.getActivity` before it's been initialized. You should remove your `contextUpdate` variable altogether and make a call to `Fragment.getActivity` instead.